# How to check the validity of data? if There are repeated Y values against X data

Tags: dataset, data, model-selection

I need to find the best-fitted curve for this data, I am not sure which model should I use? Can someone suggest me a model?

I also have doubts that this dataset is not valid. As there are multiple Y values against X.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: replied by a bot. Nice